# How to only show a gif while website loads

Tags: javascript, html

so I've been researching for a bit to get a loading screen on my website. 
I finally found one that (somewhat) works. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* display loader only if JavaScript is enabled, no JS-lib loaded at this point */
document.write('<div id="loader" style="display:table; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10000; background: #fff;">'
    + '<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;">'
    + 'loading…<br /><img src="img/loading.gif" />'
    + '</div></div>');
</script>
```

That's put into the header, and this code is put at the very bottom of the HTML (just before the closing body tag)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /* hide the loading-message */
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#loader').fadeOut(500);
  });
  </script>
    </body>
```

This works, but I realized that you can just scroll down while the loading screen is up and see the website in it's ugly, generating form. How can I make it so that you cannot view the rest of the website, and only see the loading gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `overflow: hidden;` to either the `html` or `body` tag to prevent scrolling of the page. This could be in your stylesheet (and activated with a loading class) or inline. Be sure to remove it on load as this prevents the page from scrolling.

To be absolutely sure your loading div stays within the viewport, you could also use `position: fixed;` instead of absolute.

Comment: Cheers! The position: fixed; worked :) But would you know how I could manage to turn overflow back into scroll; after the website has loaded?

Comment: With native javascript in chrome this works: to set: `window.document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"` and to reset: `window.document.body.style.overflow = ""`

Answer (score 0):

Make div with id loader position fixed instead of absolute.

```
position:fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `load` method

You can look here:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/

This is one implementation of solution

Answer (score 0):

You could make your content hidden by adding style attribute `visibility:hidden;` and when the page is loaded set it to `visibility:visible;` that will hide your content while loading.